# 2001 Honda Civic lx 2 door over heating I even put a new thermostat in it when taking the old one out there was nothing wrong with it

Tags: honda, civic, overheating

[image]still keeps running hot it had been in the shop 4 times with it over heating and the mechanic said this Honda  makes it look like he knows nothing about cars.. but changed everything out on it.. the hand will go all the way up to the H also.. but sometimes when I stop at a red light it will go up but when I start to go it will go back down some..

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Unfortunately, I'd like to tell you it's probably the head gasket which is at fault. I have an '03 Civic LX with the D17A1 engine just like yours (well had, it now has a JDM D17A2 in it). As long as I kept the coolant up to level in the radiator, it wouldn't do what you're talking about. Drive it two days, level goes down, acts just like what you're saying. Two things: bleed the system correctly. Air in the system causes what you're describing. Second, head gasket was the only fix. This is a common issue for the D17A1 engine.

Comment: Now it did have a crack in the head but they fixed it

Comment: The motor is a 1. 7

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description (happens at low speed with poor airflow), that typically means one of the following is happening:

1 - The radiator can't remove heat fast enough. That could mean a fan that is inop, or not moving enough air (I had an old Accord that had a partially working fan that would kick on, but would not provide sufficient airflow). Your civic should have two fans, are they both turning on? What happens if you cycle the air conditioner? It should force both fans on, even if the A/C system doesn't work.

2 - Insufficient coolant flow at low engine speeds. This would point to a restricted hose or bad water pump. It could also mean you are low on coolant.

3 - Related to #2, you might have air trapped in your coolant preventing sufficient heat exchange.

4 - Also related, if you have a bad radiator cap or have some other issue that prevents the system from building pressure, your coolant might be boiling. You are using a 50/50 mix of coolant, right? (using 100% water can cause corrosion and other problems, and using 100% coolant does not transfer heat as well.)

5 - You might have a mechanical problem that is causing your engine to expel too much heat. This could be something like running lean (makes the engine run hot), or a blown head gasket (directly forces hot gases into the coolant), or a cracked/warped head.

Some troubleshooting you can try:

A. Does turning the heater on help? This dumps some of the engine heat into the cabin.

B. Are you sure the coolant level is full, stable, and has been bled? If there's any question, get a pressure tester from Autozone (for free) and check for leaks. You can also check the plugs to see if you are burning coolant.

C. Does engine temperature rise at low vehicle speeds, or low engine speed? This helps narrow down if it's airflow related or coolant flow related.

D. Any check engine light or codes?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like your fan isn't running.  It gets air flow when you are moving so it runs cooler.

Comment: The fans kicks on just fine so I know it not that just had fan switch put on it

Comment: was that "fan switch" put on before the problem or after?  If you have a new issue, always suspect whatever the last fix was.   Anyway, even if the fan switch is new, it still points to the fan not always being on.  I would thoroughly check connectors and grounding as an intermittent problem points to a loose wire.  To be thorough though, did you check your water level?  Probably the best check to do though would be put a thermometer in the water.  It may not actually be overheating.  You could simply have a bad temp sending unit.